# Frameserver in Blender 2.82

Tags: video

In an older version of Blender, there was an option to export video via a Frameserver.

[image: Frame server in old Blender]

Where can I find this option in Blender 2.82? Or how can I activate it ?

[image: No frame server in Blender 2.82]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/180620/frameserve-to-external-ffmpeg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Frameserver option was removed in Blender 2.8 https://developer.blender.org/T57423
The comment from Susu    [Frameserve to external ffmpeg?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/180620/frameserve-to-external-ffmpeg)  gives a good alternative options